# Trying to figure out why BS returns an empty list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im very new at this so please forgive me. Im trying to pull the names of songs from a *Spotify* playlist using *BeautifulSoup* but am having issues. When I try to search for the tag that I want, I keep getting nothing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

result = requests.get('https://open.spotify.com/playlist/6UeSakyzhiEt4NB3UAd6NQ')
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

songs = soup.findAll("div", {"role":"row"})

print (songs)
```

Comment: if you like the answer please accept it and upvote thx

Answer (score 1):

you have to analyze the hmtl to find what you want better: below gives you the song names...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

result = requests.get('https://open.spotify.com/playlist/6UeSakyzhiEt4NB3UAd6NQ')
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

songs = soup.findAll("span", {"class":"track-name"})

for song in songs:
    print(''.join(song.findAll(text=True))+'\n')
```

Comment: I will delete mine, because you bet me by a few seconds.  I will upvote yours too.

Comment: wow... appreciate your sportsmanship, thank you